# APL / APLX: value error when using an if statement inside a for loop

Tags: apl

I'm attempting to implement quicksort in APLX, but I can't seem to fix this value error I keep getting from the statement `:If((ITEM COMPARE PIVOT)≤0)`. After some testing, I believe the problem lies with the fact that I am using an If statement inside a For loop, but I don't know why that would be a problem. Here's the entire function (or rather operator), just in case the problem lies elsewhere:

(note than COMPARE is a comparator function that I pass to quicksort)

```
(COMPARE QSORT)ARRAY
⍝ If the array has a size of 1
⍝ or less, return
:If (⍴ARRAY) ≤ 1
  ARRAY
:endif
⍝ set pivot to last element in array
PIVOTINDEX ← ⍴ARRAY
PIVOT ← PIVOTINDEX⌷ARRAY
⍝ remove pivot from array by assigning
⍝ array to all elements up to pivot index
ARRAY ← (PIVOTINDEX-1)↑ARRAY
⍝ Make empty vectors for values greater
⍝ than and less than the pivot
LESSER ← ⍳0
GREATER ← ⍳0
⍝ loop over ARRAY, place items in GREATER
⍝ or LESSER where appropriate
:For ITEM :In ARRAY
  :If((ITEM COMPARE PIVOT)≤0)
    LESSER ← LESSER,ITEM
  :Else
    GREATER ← GREATER,ITEM
  :EndIf
:EndFor
SORTED ← SORTED,(COMPARE QSORT LESSER)
SORTED ← SORTED,PIVOT
SORTED ← SORTED,(COMPARE QSORT GREATER)
SORTED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I'm afraid I'm not familiar with APLX, but here are my 0.02$ regardless:

1. You know about ⍋? So I assume this is an educational excercise... ;-)
2. There is no problem with the control-structures, but your `COMPARE` -fn does not return a result, so when you then try to use the result (by referring to `COMPARE`), that creates the error. The function header should probably be `∇ RESULT←(COMPARE QSORT)ARRAY` (*session-output is not considered "**function-result**" - this needs explicit assignment!*)
3. Also note that localizing name of variables is considered good practice.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing a return value in my COMPARE function. I was under the impression that returning values in APL was like returning values in Ruby, so thanks for the heads up on how to actually return!

Comment: As you were coding Quicksort here: while browsing Dyalog's blog yesterday, I found these 2 - might be interesting ;-)  http://www.dyalog.com/blog/2014/12/quicksort-in-apl/ and http://www.dyalog.com/blog/2016/02/quicksort-in-apl-revisited/

Comment: wow APL is much more succinct than I thought. thanks for the links!